# SQL query to match multiple values to a field in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select distinct values of Column A where Column B = any members of a set S.

Is there a way to do this directly in SQL without looping and then filtering afterwards in code?

Thanks

EDIT: The set S is a PHP array. Does this make a difference?

Comment: What flavor of mysql library in PHP are you using? [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `IN` clause with a list of values, or a subquery (not sure if supported in MySql since I use Oracle). The match can be on more than one column.

```
SELECT column_a
  FROM mytable
 WHERE column_b IN (1, 2, 3)

SELECT column_a
  FROM mytable
 WHERE column_b IN (SELECT column_c FROM myothertable)
```

Comment: Yes it is supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    columnA
FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
    columnB IN ( 'your', 'set', 'of', 'values' )
```